# cassandra key cache not populated on misses

Tags: cassandra

I'm investigating a production cassandra 1.1 performance problem:

Background: read latencies are going above a second. The ring is spread over 2 data centers, 5 nodes in each, on the east and west coasts. The nodes have 64GB of RAM. Row caching is disabled, the JVM heap size is set to 8GB, key caching is enabled with a max capacity of 2GB.

Problem: the key cache hit rate is abysmal, nearly 0%, and the despite all the misses, the cache is not filling up:
(from "nodetool info", here's the key cache info for 2 of the nodes):

Key Cache        : size 172992 (bytes), capacity 2147483616 (bytes), 112226 hits, 81631832 requests, 0.000 recent hit rate, 14400 save period in seconds

Key Cache        : size 166896 (bytes), capacity 2147483616 (bytes), 94182 hits, 62270620 requests, 0.000 recent hit rate, 14400 save period in seconds

Has anyone seen this before, where there are lots of key cache misses and lots of room in the key cache, and yet the cache is not being populated? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The key cache is designed to speed up access for existing data, not non-existing data.  You should look into why non-existing data is not being short-circuited at the bloom filter level instead.

Comment: Thanks for helping, much appreciated and I hadn't considered the idea of these requests being on non-existent data. Two follow ups: first, can you confirm that if the key-cache-miss is on data row that does exist, then the key for that row will be added to the key cache? (seems obvious but want to make sure I am not making false assumptions). And next, the client code, after making a read request for non-existent data, should be writing a new row. Would the key be added to the key cache on write? Or only after misses? thanks!!!

Comment: to close this out: we misunderstood the documentation around the caching configuration being moved from the CF level to global. The CF's had been created with caching set to rows_only, and so it appears that reads still hit the key cache, but then don't populate it on misses. We updated the CF's to allow key caching and now the hit rate is >90%. Thanks!